# Android MonkeyRunner unable to enter text

Tags: testing, android, android-testing, monkeyrunner

I recently started using MonkeyRunner to test the UI of my Android application (I am also using Espresso but wanted to play around with MonkeyRunner). The problem that I am having is that I am unable to enter text into EditText fields using the automation script.

The script navigates through my app perfectly but it doesn't seem to actually enter any text on call of the `MonkeyRunner.type()` command.

Please find my script below.

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from com.android.monkeyrunner.easy import EasyMonkeyDevice, By
import commands
import sys
import os

# starting the application and test
print "Starting the monkeyrunner script"

# connection to the current device, and return a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
easy_device = EasyMonkeyDevice(device)

apk_path = device.shell('pm path com.mysample
if apk_path.startswith('package:'):
    print "application installed."
else:
    print "not installed, install APK"
    device.installPackage('/MySample/MySample.apk')')

package ="com.mysample"
activity = ".SampleActivity"

print "Package: " + package + "Activity: " + activity

print "starting application...."
device.startActivity(component=package + '/' + activity)
print "...component started"

device.touch(205,361, "DOWN_AND_UP")
device.type("This is sample text")
MonkeyRunner.sleep(1)

result = device.takeSnapshot()

result.writeToFile("images/testimage.png",'png')
```

As you can see from the script above the text `This is sample text` should be placed in the EditText box. Both the emulator and screenshot that is taken show no text in the text field.

Am I missing a step or just doing something incorrectly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to simplify the task.
Basically, you can connect your device with `adb` and then run

```
culebra -VC -d on -t on -o myscript.py
```

The script obtains references to all of the visible Views. Edit the script and add at the end

```
no_id10.type('This is sample text')
no_id10.writeImageToFile('/tmp/image.png')
```

No need to worry about View coordinates, no need to touch and type, no need to add sleeps, etc.

**NOTE**: this is using `no_id10` as an example, the id for your `EditText` could be different

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've revised my script and I am now testing it with your AndroidViewClient tool (great work!). I have one question however - I am unable to start my activity with the 'startActivity command'. The following throws an error device.startActivity(component=component) ---------

RuntimeError: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.mysample/.activities.SampleActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.mysample/com.mysample.activities.SampleActivity} does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would **not** use the `MonkeyRunner.sleep` command, but I would rather use the `time` package and the `time.sleep` command. Just import the package

```
import time
```

and you should be good to go.

Moreover, I suggest you should wait some time between `device.touch` and `device.type`. Try with

```
device.touch(205,361, "DOWN_AND_UP")
time.sleep(1)
device.type("This is sample text")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply to my question. I've made the changes you suggested but still the same issue. I increased the timer to 10 seconds but same issue again.

Comment: Are you sure the `touch` commands is targeting the correct coordinates? If you `touch` an EditText, the software keyboard should appear.

Comment: Yeah the coords are correct - I checked using the debug monitor and only use the one emulator. I thought that it should appear but it doesn't. The app itself works fine - passes the espresso tests with no problem so not sure what the issue could be.